# Holomorphic functions in unitary disk

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $f:D \longrightarrow{D}$ holomorphic, with $D$ is  unitary disk.

Show that if $f$ has two fixed point, then $f$ is identity in $D$

I've done:

If $f(0)=0, f(a)=a, a\ne0$,  as $|f(a)|=|a|$, per Schwarz Lemma $f(z)=cz$ with $c$ a complex number, then $a=f(a)=ca$, therefore $c=1$

I can't do the case,  when $f(0)\ne0$

Comment: Reduce to the case $f(0)=0$ with a Moebius transformation.

Comment: What Möbius transformation?

Comment: f is not necessarily a automorphism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my hint in the comments was wrong. Here's how to proceed: Call $a$, $b$ the fixed points and consider $\psi$ a Moebius transformation $\psi : D\to D$ such that $\psi(a)=0$ and consider $g= \psi \circ f \circ \psi^{-1}$. Then $g$ has fixed points $0$ and $\psi(b)$.